# On transcendence base and separability

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

This is a problem in Hungerford's *Algebra*.

Let $k$ be a perfect field and $F$ an extension field of $k$ with transcendence degree 1 and $F$ is not perfect. We have to show that $F$ is separably generated over $k$ meaning that there exists an element $y\in F$ such that $F$ is separable and algebraic over $k(y)$.